# SQL Server : import txt file using first row as header

Tags: sql-server, import, text-files

I have at least 50 `.txt` files which need to be imported into SQL Server. If I do it manually in Management Studio, it's very time consuming.

These text files have different numbers of columns and are not the same. So I want to write some code to import these files which are separated by `|` and use the first row as header.

The code which I have created doesn't work. First I import it into 1 column and then split the column by defining the columns. But the issue is that I don't always know how many columns the file has.

So is there another trick to import a text file and use the first row as header? (it is the same as using the utility but instead creating a code which I can use for all 50 text files and doesn't matter amount of column each file)

This the code I created:

```
declare @cmd varchar(max)
declare @file varchar(max)
declare @folder varchar(max)

drop table #TMP 
create table #TMP (heleregel nvarchar(max))

set @folder = 'D:\...\' 
set @file = 'test'

truncate table #TMP 

SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT #TMP FROM ''' +  @folder + @file + '.txt'' 
            WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|||'',ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')

EXEC(@cmd)

DROP TABLE test

SELECT
    ltrim(rtrim(dbo.UFN_SEPARATES_COLUMNS(heleregel, 1, '|'))) as test1,
    ltrim(rtrim(dbo.UFN_SEPARATES_COLUMNS(heleregel, 2, '|'))) as test2,
    ltrim(rtrim(dbo.UFN_SEPARATES_COLUMNS(heleregel, 3, '|'))) as test3,
    ltrim(rtrim(dbo.UFN_SEPARATES_COLUMNS(heleregel, 4, '|'))) as test4
INTO 
    test
FROM 
    #TMP
```

Comment: Powershell? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3208/automating-flat-file-sql-server-imports-with-powershell/

Comment: try to use openrowset and FMT file